# Trigger event when toggling between div and textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so Im building an application in Laravel, but my problem is with jQuery. I am creating a comment section for some posts. Adding the comments work fine. Under each post all the comments for the particular post are listed. If the comment is made by you, an edit button is shown. If you press the edit button a few things will happen:

- the p-tag containing the comment is replaced with a textarea (maintaining the same content/text)
- the edit button changes text to "Save" (instead of "Edit")
- the button also changes some classes and therefore styling
- the button gets a class of "save-mode"

Im trying to make so that when the button has the class of save-mode, an event should get triggered, thus updating the comment in the database.
Now, almost all the pieces work fine separately but the Ajax call is not fired when the button is pressed. And I just cant see why. Its worth mentioning that the Ajax call does work. But the if-statement that is supposed to trigger it doesn't.

There must be something wrong with my logic.

Ive included a snippet, and Im guessing theres something wrong in the editComment function. Ive removed the blade syntax, styling and surrounding markup. But you can see the same problem in this snippet.

I really appreciate any help I can get to illuminate my own stupidity. 
Thank you.

```js
$("#edit-save-btn").on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 editComment($(this));
});

function editComment(btn){
 const id = btn.attr('value');
 const comment = btn.closest('.col-md-3').prev().find('.comment-text');
 const commentHTML = $.trim(comment.text());

 if(btn.hasClass('save-mode')){
      console.log('this need to get triggered');
  //updateComment(id, commentHTML);
  return;
 }

 btn.toggleClass('save-mode');

 const editable = $('<textarea />').css({'width': '100%'});
 editable.val(commentHTML);
 comment.replaceWith(editable);
 editable.focus();
 btn.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success').html('<i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Lagre');
 editable.blur(editableTextBlured);
}

function editableTextBlured() {
 $("#edit-save-btn").removeClass('btn-success save-mode').addClass('btn-primary').html('<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Rediger');
 var text = $(this).val();
 viewableText = $('<p class="comment-text">');
 viewableText.html(text);
 $(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
 $(viewableText).click(editComment);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment-post clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <p class="comment-text">
      comment
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-3">                  
    <form class="pull-right right-margin" action="" method="post">
      <button value="{{$comment->id}}" class="btn edit-comment btn-primary btn-xs" id="edit-save-btn"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try $(document).on("click","#edit-save-bt", function(e) instead of $("#edit-save-btn").on('click', function(e){

Comment: I wish that would make a difference, but I doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the button will trigger the blur event of textarea.

At the function `editableTextBlured`, your removed the class `save-mode`, so `btn.hasClass('save-mode')` is return `false`, it can't trigger save.

It's like this:

blur -> remove className save-mode -> btn.hasClass('save-mode') -> false, can't trigger save.

Wish it can help for you :)